# Add new columns to excel file from multiple datasets with Pandas in Google Colab

Tags: pandas, append, google-colaboratory, multiple-columns, export-to-excel

I'm trying to add some columns to a excel file after some data but I'm not having good results just overwriting what I have. Let me give you some context: I'm reading a [csv](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/miroslavsabo/young-people-survey/download?datasetVersionNumber=2), for each column I'm using a for to value_counts and then create a frame from this value_counts here the code for just one column:

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.read_csv('responses.csv')

datatoexcel = data['Music'].value_counts().to_frame()

datatoexcel.to_excel('savedataframetocolumns.xlsx') #Name of the file
```

This works like this ...

[image]
[image]

And with that code for only one column I have the format that I actually need for excel.

But the problem is when I try to do it with for to all the columns and then "Append" to excel the following dataframes using this formula:

```
for columnName in df:
    datasetstoexcel = df.value_counts(columnName).to_frame()
    print(datasetstoexcel)
    # Here is my problem with the following line the .to_excel
    x.to_excel('quickgraph.xlsx') #I tried more code lines but I'll leave this one as base
```

The result that I want to reach is this one:

[image]

I'm really close to finish this code, some help here please!

Comment: writing to excel file inside for loop may not be a good idea. posted the answer. do try it out and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

Sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "col1": [1,2,3,4],
    "col2": [5,6,7,8],
    "col3": [9, 9, 11, 12],
    "col4": [13, 14, 15, 16],
})
```

Find value counts and add to a list

```
li = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
    li.append(value_counts)
```

concat all the dataframes inside li and write to excel

```
pd.concat(li, axis=1).to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: actually it works just at the end give this error --> single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: hope the error is resolved. if not pls share the sample data, the code you tried and the stack trace. we can help.

Comment: The error is solved thanks, it works perfectly, thank you!